# How to remove this XSS from JSP?

Tags: jsp, xss

I have an input tag defined in my JSP as :

```
<input type="text" name="transCurrency" maxlength="10" size="10" value="<%=beanUseVec.getValue("transCurrency")%>" />
```

The corresponding function `getValue()` is defined in `beanUseVec.java` as :

```
public String getValue(String vectK)
{
    if(uEnVec != null && uEnVec.containsKey(vectK))
    return (String)uEnVec.get(vectK);
    else
    return "";
}
```

When I did a [veracode](http://www.veracode.com/) scan for my files, I found XSS error being shown in the line :

```
<input type="text" name="transCurrency" maxlength="10" size="10" value="<%=beanUseVec.getValue("transCurrency")%>" />
```

It  points out that `<%=beanUseVec.getValue("transCurrency")%>` is a XSS risk. Normally for other XSS risks in JSP, I use jstl `c:out` tag, which I think cannot be used here, since `getValue()` is not a POJO function, it's just a function which returns a string and `c:out` needs a variable of the POJO function to be called .

Can someone suggest any other way to get rid of this XSS issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the output to a `request` variable and display it using `c:out` tag

```
<%
String output = beanUseVec.getValue("transCurrency");
request.setAttribute("output",output);
%>

<input type="text" name="transCurrency" maxlength="10" size="10" value="<c:out value='${output}'/>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks let me check that .